# como validar si todos los elementos de mi array empiezan con mayuscula en Javascript ,

Tags: javascript

**Por ejemplo:**

```
const frutas=['Fresa','Papaya','Arandanos','Naranja','Platano'];
```

```
const frutas=['Fresa','Papaya','Arandanos','Naranja','Platano']; 
const empiezanMayus =frutas.every((nombre)=>{ 
  for(i=0;i<nombre.length;i++){ 
    if(frutas[i][0].toUpperCase()===frutas[i].slice(0,1)){ 
      return true 
    }else{ 
      return false 
    } 
  }
}) 
console.log(empiezanMayus)
```

Comment: const frutas=['Fresa','Papaya','Arandanos','Naranja','Platano'];
    const empiezanMayus =frutas.every((nombre)=>{
    for(i=0;i<nombre.length;i++){
    if(frutas[i][0].toUpperCase()===frutas[i].slice(0,1)){

       return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
    }})

    console.log(empiezanMayus)

Comment: Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Para agregar contenido relevante a tu pregunta, debes pulsar en [edit]. Además, explica qué problemas has tenido con el código que proporcionas.

Comment: @JuanHeart tu codigo luce bien , solo cambia el every por filter, yez eso, compara la longitud del arreglo original y el del dilger por ejemplo ```frutas.length == empiezanMayus.length```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno esta la forma basica y la forma avanzada... y me imagino que hay otras muchas formas de hacerlo, en este caso yo implementaria foreach y every

Con **Foreach**:

```js
const frutas = ['Fresa', 'Papaya', 'Arandanos', 'naranja', 'Platano'];
let empiezanMayus = true;

frutas.forEach((nombre) => {
  // Verifica si la primera letra del nombre no es igual a su versión en mayúscula
  if (nombre[0] !== nombre[0].toUpperCase()) {
    empiezanMayus = false;
  }
});

console.log(empiezanMayus);
```

Con **Every**:

```js
const frutas = ['Fresa', 'Papaya', 'Arandanos', 'naranja', 'Platano'];
const empiezanMayus = frutas.every((nombre) => {
  // Compara la primera letra del nombre con su versión en mayúscula
  return nombre[0] === nombre[0].toUpperCase();
});
console.log(empiezanMayus);
```

como podras ver elimine la parte de slice, ya que en javascript si tienes una cadena de texto:

ejemplo: `let nombre = 'naranja';`

puedes acceder al primer carecter con `nombre[0]`

El resultado sigue siendo el mismo, si el script detecta que una palabra/elemento en el array no inicia con mayuscula, retornara `false` inmediantamente, de lo contrario retornara `true`.